# Use the secant method to find the time at which $y(t) = 0$.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Hi I need to solve the following exercise.

1)Apply both the Runge-Kutta boostrapping and the Adams-Bashforth method to solve the initial-value problem
$y' =\cos(t)+y−y^3$, $y(0)=2$
up to time $t = 6$ using a step-size of $h = 0.1$. Compute the (absolute) error at $t = 6$, given that the
exact value is −0.4845092473 (10 dp). What happens to the error if you halve the step size?

2) Use the secant method to find the time at which $y(t) = 0$.

*Hint: Find the step i such that y(t) crosses 0 between $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$. Then find a step size $h_i$ such that $y(t_i + h_i) = 0$.*

*Note: You should give the estimated values of y for times up to 0.5, and for the final time.*

I have already solved the part 1), but I am really struggling with the second one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the warning -.-

Comment: it is. the starting solution is y(0) = 2

Comment: I found the roots of the function using Adams-Bashford method, I am not sure they are the values of y, the question simply wants me to find the value of t at which y(t) = 0.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Well-done. Now, is your question about finding $t_i$ or about implementing the secant method?

Comment: my question is to find ti

Comment: A good strategy to check whether a continuos function has crossed the x-axis is to multipy $y_i$ with $y_{i+1}$. If the product is negative, then $y$ has crossed the x-axis (between $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$)

Comment: and how do I do that in Matlab? Should I write a method that does that or Should I write a method which does that or should I just try the values until I figure that out?

Comment: To do this in matlab, you can write a for loop that iterates along the values of $y$ and finds when $y_i\cdot y_{i+1}<=0$. If you're proficient in matlab, you can do this in one line by vectorizing the operation and using the matlab command "find".

Comment: I have found the solution! Thanks a lot.